# When I try to install Linux on older PC 32bit I get black screen with blinking cursor. How to fix?

Tags: debian, ubuntu, system-installation, x86, 32bit

I have an old PC that used to run Windows XP (32bit). There are two hard drives. I tried to turn it on again, but Windows would not boot. I then decided to install Linux. I tried Ubuntu, Xubuntu, Debian, and Silaz (32-bit versions). They all do the same thing - they start booting, I get a menu, I select install... and then get a black screen with a blinking cursor.

I first assumed it was the somewhat rare graphic card. So I uninstalled it and put a standard PCI card in — same issue.

I then removed the slave drive and tried to install it with just the master. Same issue. I then removed the master, jumpered the slave as the new master, and tried again - the same result.

I then started the Debian CD (had the nicest boot menu), went into isolinux, and added nomodeset to the kernel prompt. No change.

What else could I do/try?

It is a Pentium 4 2.4 GHZ. The board states it is a "Medion MD5000 v1.0".

Comment: Please [edit] the question and post hardware specifications. That a PC was sold with a 32-Windows Windows doesn't mean it has a 32-bit only CPU. Many of XP vintage had 64-bit CPU already but the Windows version bundled was always 32-bit. If actually 32-bit your options are extremely limited, most if not all of the distros you have been trying are Out of Support and shouldn't be used, period. If it has a 64-bit CPU then use a 64-bit OS.

Comment: @ChanganAuto the P4 (Northwood) is a [32bit CPU](https://www.cpu-world.com/CPUs/Pentium_4/TYPE-Desktop%20Pentium%204%20Northwood.html)

Answer (score 0):

First things first:
Be sure to ask your searchengine of choice for your exact mainboard model (and bios-version) AND linux AND black screen.  It could be any number of issues :-/

Personally, I'd remove **all** hard-drives and any unneeded hardware to try and boot a live-system at first.  Something like [Antix](https://antixlinux.com), to be on the safe side (old drivers and such).  [Ventoy](https://www.ventoy.net/en/index.html) is my go-to-tool for multiboot-usb-keys.

Then I'd add the hardware back in, piece by piece, boot by boot, to see if it's a hardware issue and who's the culprit.

May be an issue with RAM (not enough? broken?) or power-supply as well.

Comment: The power supply works fine, there is 512 MB RAM in the machine, also fine (according to the BIOS RAM check).

Comment: The Bios is Phoenix Award BIOS 6.00pg. The motherboard is called "Medion MD5000 v1.0". The CPU is INTEL Pentium 4 2.4Ghz.

Comment: 512MB RAM is a tight squeeze for current Distros.  You should try and give Antix or PuppyOS a spin.  Maybe it's just not enough Memory to handle current graphical desktops.